# iPhone Vibration Control

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to write an app that alerts users based on number of vibrations. There are 8 possible vibrations... Each mean something else, they are in the format of from 1 to 8 consecutive vibrations...

Jist is: I need to know how I can vibrate the phone 8 times in a row?

Also: if it's possible to *HOLD* the vibration for more than one second and just 8 seconds, then I just need an 8 second vibration, not 8 times in a row.

```
vibrateCount = vibrateCount +1;
if(vibrateCount <= 5) {
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
else {

      //vibrated 5 times already kill timer and stop vibrating
      [vibrateTimer invalidate];

   }
```

In a timer - but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about using a for loop instead of a timer?